# Angular (4+) - best practices / tips

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular JS, I have generated the Angular Project from Angular CLI (Angular core is at 5.1.0).  I would like to the best practices for writing a good UI.

It would be a great help to me if anyone can share the best practices and tips.

Comment: For better understanding, you should refer angular docs.
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: And remember, it's NOT Angular JS, simply Angular or Angular 5

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn angular5 with rxjs this would be great tutorial https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/